# Shopify public app development from local development environment deployment in Shopify app store

Tags: shopify

How to develop the Shopify public app development from local development environment and deployment in the app store ? please kindly help to share development step's or example code did in the your environment

Answer (score 0):

1) Go here https://app.shopify.com/services/partners/api_clients and create an APP.

2) Set the **App URL (required)** to your local URL folder.

3) Set the **Redirection URL (required)** where you will generate your token locally again:

4) Add the application in your store using the following logic:

https://**{shop}**.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id=**{api_key}**&scope=**{scopes}**&redirect_uri=**{redirect_uri}**

( more on this here https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/17056443-how-to-generate-a-shopify-api-token )

**Note: If 4 doesn't work you may need to add SLL on your local server and use your SSL links for 1 & 2.**

And you should have a local app that can be developed now.

Comment: Hi,i am having one folder "shopify-tester" in local and how to give the APP URL and Redirection URL

Comment: How do you access the folder trough your browser? Use the same logic for the URL's. At the end Shopify will add an iframe that will point to your local folder. So something in does lines: `http://localhost/shopify-tester`

Comment: ok,both app url and redirection url are same ? 
(http://localhost/shopify-tester/) shall i use the sample github mentioned in the page ?

Comment: hi one more i create app but nothing is display in the app page how to add the content and display in the front-end ?